# How to parse multiple json data in python?

Tags: python, json

my device will sent json data like this:

```
[{"channel":924125000, "sf":10, "time":"2017-05-11T16:56:15", "gwip":"192.168.1.125", "gwid":"00004c4978dbf5b4", "repeater":"00000000ffffffff", "systype":5, "rssi":-108.0, "snr":17.0, "snr_max":23.3, "snr_min":10.8, "macAddr":"00000000000000c3", "data":"4702483016331210179183", "frameCnt":1, "fport":2}]
```

but sometimes i received multiple json data(two or more):

```
[{"channel":924125000, "sf":10, "time":"2017-05-11T16:56:15", "gwip":"192.168.1.125", "gwid":"00001c497b48dbf5", "repeater":"00000000ffffffff", "systype":5, "rssi":-108.0, "snr":17.0, "snr_max":23.3, "snr_min":10.8, "macAddr":"00000000050100e8", "data":"4702483016331210179183", "frameCnt":1, "fport":2}],[{"channel":924125000, "sf":10, "time":"2017-05-11T16:56:15", "gwip":"192.168.1.125", "gwid":"00001c497b48dbf5", "repeater":"00000000ffffffff", "systype":5, "rssi":-108.0, "snr":17.0, "snr_max":23.3, "snr_min":10.8, "macAddr":"00000000050100e8", "data":"4702483016331210179183", "frameCnt":1, "fport":2}]
```

when i parse multiple json data

```
json_Dict = json.loads(jsonData)
```

then

`File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 369, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 303 - line 1 column 1818 (char 302 - 1817)`

how can parse every multiple json data ?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

because you have multiple objects in your json you should include them in a list :

```
json_List = json.loads('[' + jsonData + ']')
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste it in a Tool like [JSONLINT](https://jsonlint.com/)

and you get:

> Error: Parse error on line 17:
>   ...": 1,    "fport": 2}], [{    "channel": 924
>   ---------------------^
>   Expecting 'EOF', got ','

which is the cause of your error. This is not *valid* JSON.
The correct structure would be something like `[[...],[...]]`. You have `[...],[...]`, which is not correct.